# Why don't I get variable in template?

Tags: angular

I try to pass variable `filteredValues` to template `patternTemplate`:

```
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="patternTemplate; context: filteredValues"> </ng-container>
```

Template is:

```
<ng-template #patternTemplate let-filteredValues="filteredValues">
   {{ filteredValues | json }}
</ng-template>
```

Why I can not get  `{{ filteredValues | json }}` inside template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to this

```
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="patternTemplate; context:{ filteredValues: filteredValues}"> 
</ng-container>
```

Explanation:

```
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="tmplate; context: { x : y }">
...
<ng-template #tmplate let-z="x">
  {{ z | json }}
</ng-template>
```

in above `x` is the one you use like `let-z=x`, and `y` is the value you want to bind, and `z` is the name you can reference in your template

Comment: Could you edit your answer without x, y I am confused by this

Comment: @Jony the first line is what you need to change, the rest is explanation
so only change `context: { filteredValues : filteredValues }`

Answer (score 0):

You are close. You either have to specify `$implicit` context or name your values passed into template context.

Either

```
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="patternTemplate; context: {$implicit:filteredValues}">
<ng-template #patternTemplate let-passedValues> <- passedValues = filteredValues
```

or name your param

```
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="patternTemplate; context: {yourName:filteredValues}">
<ng-template #patternTemplate let-passedValues="yourName"> <- passedValues = filteredValues as it will be assigned trough "yourName"
```

`$implicit` cant be mixed with other proprty names and all will work, eg

```
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="patternTemplate; context: {$implicit:"val1",somethingElse:"somethingElseValue"}">
<ng-template #patternTemplate let-comesAsImplicit let-comesWithName="somethingElse">

{{comeAsImplicit}} will evaluate to "val1" and {{comesWithName}} evaluates to "somethingElseValue" </ng-template>
```